# Selenium Python: Select <a href="#" </a>

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I select a button with the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="js-buy ncss-brand ta-sm-c u-uppercase pt3-sm pr5-sm pb3-sm pl5-sm pt2-lg pb2-lg d-sm-b d-lg-ib test-buyable ncss-btn bg-black text-color-white">Kaufen 210,00&nbsp;€</a>
```

The following is on
I want to click on the black 'Kaufen' button. I have tried the following:

```
buy = ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="j_c29"]/div[1]/a')))
buy.click()
```

I get error:

```
File "/Users/xxx/test.py", line 101, in <module>
    obj.run()
  File "/Users/xxx/test.py", line 66, in run
    buy = ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="j_c29"]/div[1]/a')))
  File "/Users/xxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the entire error stack trace please?

Comment: @DebanjanB updated, however it doesnt give me any message at the end

Comment: You could select `By.CSS_SELECTOR` instead: `div.buying-tools-component a.js-buy`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to `click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* along with `expected_conditions` clause as **element_to_be_clickable** instead of `presence_of_element_located` and you can use either of the following options :

- *Partial Link Text* :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Kaufen"))).click()
  ```
- *XPATH* :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='js-buy ncss-brand ta-sm-c u-uppercase pt3-sm pr5-sm pb3-sm pl5-sm pt2-lg pb2-lg d-sm-b d-lg-ib test-buyable ncss-btn bg-black text-color-white' and contains(.,'Kaufen')]"))).click()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code:**

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='j_c29']/div[1]/a"))).click()
```

If you want to remove the "Deine Cookie-Einstellungen" popup use this code just before the code above:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div"))).click()
```

Comment: Please explain why this would work compared to the original code.

Comment: @Sid, are you getting exactly the same error code as you posted above?